# Content below full screen header makes the header/whole page(?) overflowing to the right slightly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, width

I'm kinda new to these but I have successfully made my full-screen header and it seems to be working fine, the problem is that whenever I add any content below my header it just makes the whole page(?), or the header has a slightly bigger width, which resulted from a horizontal scrollbar below.

My HTML :

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

body :not(.banner-container) {
  z-index: 2;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

header .navbar-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


header .navbar-container .website-logo img {
max-height: 2rem;
}

header .navbar-container .content-navigator ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
  gap: 2rem;
}

header .navbar-container .content-navigator ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  color: white;
}


header .navbar-container .content-navigator ul li a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

header video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  filter: brightness(40%);
  z-index: 0;
}

header .gradient-block-fade {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(30, 30, 30, 1));
  z-index: 2;
}
/* other styling below */
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <video autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="css/imgsrc/gameplay.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="gradient-block-fade">
        <!-- div untuk gradient block-->
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-container">
      <div class="website-logo">
        <a href="#Home"><img src="css/imgsrc/osu-icon-placeholder.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="content-navigator">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#Search">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Rankings">Rankings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Forum">Forum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Support">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
    <!-- other content below -->
</body>
```

I tried other's solution that has the same problem for me but it doesn't seem to work. also I seemed to found out that resizing the window to a smaller width fixes it but fullscreen window the problems occur. also found out that deleting my header makes the other content normal and no right overflow and also keeping the header only makes no overflow.

Answer (score 0):

set `height` on `header` to 100%, then scrollbar doesn't appear.

```
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```